# Why is member.user.presence.status returning undefined? | discord.js v13

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to get the total of online, offline, idle and DND members in the server. Presence intents are enabled in the developers panel and are included in the code:

```
const client = new discord.Client({ partials: ["CHANNEL"], intents: [discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING]});
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')
```

Code:

```
    let onlineMembers = (await guild.members.fetch()).filter((member) => !member.user.bot && member.user.presence.status == 'online');
    let offlineMembers = (await guild.members.fetch()).filter((member) => !member.user.bot && member.user.presence.status == 'dnd'); 
    let awayMembers = (await guild.members.fetch()).filter((member) => !member.user.bot && member.user.presence.status == 'offline');
    let dndMembers = (await guild.members.fetch()).filter((member) => !member.user.bot && member.user.presence.status == 'idle');
```

I'm not understanding what could be the issue, even though `status` does exist

EDIT:

Also tried this, doesn't work, same error:

```
    let onlineMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == "online").size;
    let offlineMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == "offline").size; 
    let awayMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == "idle").size;
    let dndMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == "dnd").size;
```

EDIT 2: using `member?.presence.status` doesn't work for both codes attempted

Comment: `member?.presence.status` maybe?

Comment: tried with both codes, still no luck, same error :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)s don't have presences. Only [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)s do. The member's presence is either `null` or `offline` when they are offline

```js
let onlineMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence?.status == "online").size
let offlineMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.presence || member.presence.status == "offline").size
let awayMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence?.status == "idle").size
let dndMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence?.status == "dnd").size
```

Use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) to check if it's [nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish)

Comment: Thanks, i was using optional chaining but after member as i was told to do so by @Leau